# Use custom DNS records

Tags: dns, dns-servers, plesk

I have a dedicated server running Ubuntu and Plesk. I have a primary domain on this server but will also be running several other sites and I would like to be able to set the DNS records for those to something such as:

ns1.maindomain.com

ns2.maindomain.com

I found a couple Plesk tutorials on how to do this and follow them, but when I try to change the DNS records for a domain on GoDaddy I get an error saying that ns1.maindomain.com is not a valid record.

Any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: If you do not absolutely know what you are doing, I would recommend that you do not do this. Why? Because you will very likely get yourself into a scenario that you cannot fix easily if at all. I am seeing a troubling trend of vanity NS's as all the rage. The problem is, this is NOT a good idea. I was a web host for a long time and I know the show stopping gotchas that are never cautioned anywhere and especially on the sites that advised vanity NS's.

Comment: One of the things @closetnoc is referring to is that your 'vanity' nameservers will be pointing to a static IP address.  If your host changes IP for some reason, your DNS will break.  On the other hand, if you use your host's nameservers and the IP changes, you can be almost certain that they will change the nameservers IP address as well.

Comment: @Steve Yes. Bingo! Anything comes along that breaks the domain name to IP address mapping for any reason forces the SOA for the domain name to become unreachable and therefore impossible to fix with the catch-22 scenario the OP created for himself. Any SOA for a domain name MUST NOT reside on a DNS that is dependent upon the domain name without also residing on DNSs on another network and domain name. You are about to create a HUGE problem if not done right. Cheers Mate!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set up ns1.maindomain.com and ns2 at your domain registrar?  Some places call it *child nameservers*, some call it *registry hosts*.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I know how to point a domain to a specific name server. What I'm looking here is to actually create a name server such as ns1.maindomain.com with my own domain.

Comment: @GuillermoCarone then have another look at the answer.  This is how to create the nameserver name, NOT how to point a domain to a nameserver

Comment: You are right, sorry for missreading that. I have managed to create the NS thanks to your tips :)